# UItextView and NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a strange error.

```
MyController A
{
@ syntesize myUITextView;
}

MyController B {


MyControllerA *controller = ....
NSSTring *myString = " hello";
controller.myUITextView.text = myString;
 NSLog(@"%@",myUITextView.text) =   (null)

NSLog(@"%@",myString) = hello

}
```

when i print controller.myUITextView it's null, what i am doing wrong, please ?

thanks four your answers

Answer (score 1):

`NSSTring *myString = " hello";`

`"hello"` is not an ObjectiveC string, it's a C string. You should add `@` before like this: `@"hello"`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myString = @"hello";
controller.myUITextView.text = myString;
NSLog(@"%@",controller.myUITextView.text) ;

NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```

Try this

Comment: it's the same thing. i am doing : controller.myTextview.text=myString; (null) and when doing NSLog(@"%@",myString); it's strange

Comment: No its not "hello" is not an ObjectiveC string, it's a C string. You should add @ before like this: @"hello" as @jv42 mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not logging what you think you're logging. This line...

```
NSLog(@"%@",myUITextView.text);
```

is missing the controller variable prefix so it should be:

```
NSLog(@"%@",controller.myUITextView.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you initialize `myUITextView` in `MyController A` (or bind it in Interface Builder) properly? Seems like `controller.myUITextView` is nil.

Comment: I have done like this : IBOUtlet myUITextView ; in IB myUITextview = some text.